# Bone dissapears in edit mode, but seen in pose mode?

Tags: armature

There are no constraints on it.

[image]

Once I go into edit mode, it's gone! I can't find it and I can't delete it, it just come back when I go back to pose mode.

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my very stupid question.  I hope this serves well for anyone who happens to stumble across this.

It was hiding in edit mode but not in pose mode.  I think there should be a better way for blender to handle trying to delete hidden bones.  Because it just gives you a menu and it does nothing.  When you come back in pose mode the bone still there. Give me an error message at least?